# Calculate phase of impedance

Tags: impedance, reflection-coefficient

I've seen [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/how-to-calculate-magnitude-and-phase-different-of-impedence#_=_) and thought I understood the basic concepts.

When I attempt to solve for phase given \$Z = 60 + j10\$ I end up with 9.46. However, my professor has given the answer as 39.81. I am told that the phase angle of 39.81 is derived from the complex reflection coefficient, and I understand that the reflection coefficient must be complex, but I simply calculate it as 0.128 and don't understand how to derive it as a complex number.

**Here is the question exactly as provided:**

> A signal source, which has a characteristic impedance of 50 ohms, is
> connected to a load impedance of 60+j10 ohms determine the following:
>
> - a) The return loss;
> - b) How much power will enter the load in dBm if the source power is 10mW;
> - c) The VSWR (think: will there be many standing waves s present?)
> - d) The phase of the signal reflected back to the source.
>
> There was no diagram provided, solely the text above. The answers as
> provided are as follows:
>
> - (a) Return loss, 17.85dB
> - (b) Mismatch Loss, 0.072dB, Power through is 9.928dBm
> - (c) VSWR = 1.29
> - (d) Phase of the reflection coefficient is 39.81 degrees

I got a, b and c correct which means I must have calculated the reflection coefficient. I know the reflection coefficient needs an imaginary part but I have no idea where the value of it comes from.

I calculated the reflection coefficient to be 0.128.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you are trying to solve? You are correct in that the phase angle of Z is 9.46 degrees. However there is no mention of a reflection coefficient. I feel you are leaving out a crucial part of the problem.

Comment: Using Mathematica: `ptZ = 60 + 10 I` and `{Abs[ptZ], Arg[ptZ] 180 /\[Pi]} // N` equals `{60.8276, 9.46232}` The angle is in degrees. Is this an RF problem as the information does not seem to be complete. What is the formula for the reflection coefficient that your instructor has provided to you?

Comment: Details of the transmission line are required.

Comment: I've now added the question in whole from my professor. It is indeed an RF problem, but there was no transmission line diagram.

Comment: $$\Gamma = \frac {Z_L - Z_0} {Z_L + Z_0}$$ This will be a complex quantity. It has a magnitude and phase. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cb9zRNItSrc) video.